# Is it possible to run TensorFlow in GPU mode from Java application?

Tags: java, tensorflow

I want to train my own dataset using one of the pre-trained modules form TensorFlow object detection module using Python, and after, I want to run the trained dataset in Java. I have already installed and tested TensorFlow for Java. But it is running only on CPU.

As I search on the internet, in Java it is not possible to train TensorFlow, so for training, I am using Python, and then for running I want to use Java, but the problem is GPU, I don't know if it is possible to run from Java.

**My workflow is something like this:**

- Get dataset ready
- Train dataset using one the pre-trained modules (from TensorFlow
  Object-Detection SSD_mobilenet_v1)
- Reading frames from the camera using OpenCV
- Detect object using my own train dataset by TensorFlow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow for Java does support GPU.

> If your Linux system has an NVIDIA® GPU and your TensorFlow Java program requires GPU acceleration, then add the following to the project's pom.xml instead:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>libtensorflow</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.tensorflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>libtensorflow_jni_gpu</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that GPU is only available if the system meets the [GPU support requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/install/install_linux#determine_which_tensorflow_to_install) and is only available on Linux systems at this point.

([Installing TensorFlow for Java](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/install/install_java))

Although GPU is currently unavailable on Windows, a comment in an issue for [GPU support for Java in windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16660) suggests they are actively working on it.

Comment: Hmm, so it means that on Windows it is not possible but only on Linux?

Comment: "GPU acceleration is available via Maven only for Linux and only if your system meets the requirements for GPU." I will note that they appear to be close to a release which will allow this.

Comment: Thanks! That will be great that they release a cross-platform Java wrapper to TensorFlow for both CPU and GPU to run TensorFlow from a Java application.